# Can I reference a Sqlite CTE in more than one DML statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

In a single statement, I want to update one set of rows and delete another set, both based on some CTE's.  However, when I execute it, the second DML, the DELETE, complains as if the CTE's are no longer available.  Is this not possible in Sqlite?

I looked at the [WITH reference for Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) but the only thing I found was in the Caveat section and that was about compound statements, which is not what I am doing here.

Here is my SQL with the contents of the CTE's removed because it has some proprietary stuff in there and because I don't think it matters to the question (but let me know if that's not correct):

```
with cteOldAboutCmds as (
  ...
)
, cteFrequency as (
  ...
)
, cteNewAboutCmdMaster as (
  ...
)

update cmds 
set freqrankalltime = freqrankalltime + (select fr from cteFrequency) 
where id = (select id from cteNewAboutCmdMaster);

delete 
from cmds
where id in (select id from cteOldAboutCmds);
```

I also tried wrapping the above in `begin transaction;` and `commit transaction;` but that didn't help.

The error message is: "no such table: cteOldAboutCmds".

Comment: No, `common-table-expressions` can only be referenced by the immediate following command.  Perhaps you can create a temporary table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE is part of a single SQL statement, which is pretty much its whole point.

To have named queries available for multiple statements, use [views](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html). If you don't wont to affect other connections, use temporary views.

Comment: Thank you, that led me to the solution I needed.  I am going to answer my own question too, just to show my final SQL for others, using the formatting capabilities unavailable within a comment...

Answer (score 1):

I have already accepted CL's answer but I want to format the code I ended up using, for others' benefit:

```
begin transaction;

create temp view OldAboutCmds as
select *
from...;

create temp view Frequency as
select...;

create temp view NewAboutCmdMaster as
select...;

update cmds 
set ...
where ...;

delete 
from cmds
where ...;

commit transaction;

drop view OldAboutCmds;
drop view Frequency;
drop view NewAboutCmdMaster;
```

Comment: A transaction is not a connection; you might want to drop the views.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In my experience, Sqlite doesn't keep the views after the transaction completes but in the spirit of cleanliness and completeness, and in case I am wrong and they linger somehow, I added the drop's.

Comment: Temporary tables/view are kept for the duration of the connection.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I usually close my connections so that would explain that.